# Apply javascript just in a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have coded a few lines which extract the URL of all the img tags in the page.
Ok everything works well but I wonder if there is a way to apply my code in a special div in the page!!!?
I mean I want to get URL of img tags from a div not from the whole page body.
I hope that I explained clearly what I meant :)
Any solution would be appreciated

```
       function getURL() {
              var url = [];
              var a = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
              for (var i=0, j = a.length; i<j; i++)
              {
                   if (/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/im.test(a[i].getAttribute('src')))
                   {
                      url.push(a[i].getAttribute('src'));
                   }
              }
               document.write(url);
       }
```

Comment: you do not need to use the 'j' variable in your for loop. Also note that 'j' was not declared hence it lives in the global scope

Answer (score 2):

Replace `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` with `yourElement.getElementsByTagName('img');`

Comment: Also consider using a library for these kind of functions, like prototype or jquery. With jquery you can select all images inside a element with just ```$('#yourElement img')```

Answer (score 2):

Change your function to accept a startElement parameter, then call the getElementsByTagName on the passed element

```
   function getURL(startElement) {
          var url = [];
          var a = startElement.getElementsByTagName('img');
          for (var i=0, i < a.length; i++)
          {
               if (/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/im.test(a[i].getAttribute('src')))
               {
                  url.push(a[i].getAttribute('src'));
               }
          }
          return url; // return the result instead of writing it
   }
```

Say you have this markup

```
<div id='myDiv'><img src='test.jpg'/></div>
```

You could then call

```
var urls = getUrl(document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

Also I suggest not using document.write, open dev tools (usually F12) and use console.log instead,

```
console.log(urls);
```